# How to update NTP-deamon on a Debian Squeeze (Proxmox 2.x)?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, ntp, proxmox

Because of security issue in NTP (CVE-2014-9295) I need to update NTP-deamon on a Debian Squeeze (it is the Proxmox 2.x installation). The problem is that it is a productional system and I can not test the update commands on a test system. So, I need to know clearly how to update this system. I am very thankful to people who help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a test system, then make one for yourself:

1. Install Virtualbox, VMware Workstation, etc. on your workstation.
2. Install a Debian Squeeze server within #1 so that its configuration matches production. (You're using configuration management, right?!? So this should be really easy)
3. Take a snapshot of the VM.
4. Test upgrading. If upgrade fails, revert to the snapshot and try again.

That's really all you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but at the moment I can not create a test invironment.

Comment: Sorry, but you need one. Advocate for yourself. Virtualbox is free. You *cannot* call yourself a professional sysadmin if you are unable to do this sort of rudimentary testing.